# Is there a way to replace .zapierrc by environment variables?

Tags: zapier, zapier-cli

We are about to integrate our Zapier development workflow with CircleCI and it seems the deploy key present under `~/.zapierrc` is a problem.

I cannot find any documentation regarding the deploy key and environment variables. We definitely do not want to include a file under source control with deploy keys or credentials, so what is the correct alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the environment variable `ZAPIER_DEPLOY_KEY` with the content of the `deployKey` property of the JSON contained in the `~/.zapierrc` file and it will work as expected.